# What does ! above = mean

Tags: notation

Can someone please explain what the symbol $\stackrel{!}{=}$, consisting of an exclamation mark (!) above an equals sign (=) means? Below is the example I'm trying to decipher:

---

The normalization factor is chosen such that in average, Dynamic Θ Time passes as fast as physical time. In practice it is determiend by the condition that the interval in Dynamic Θ Time corresponding to a 4-year reference period [$T_0$, $T_1$] should be of exactly the same length:

$T_1 - T_0 \stackrel{!}{=} \int_{T_0}^{T_1} a(t) dt$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my classes I use it to indicate anxiety.  So an equals with ! over it means "we want to show this equality is true".  An equals without ! means "I am asserting this is true".

I don't know how universal this convention is, though.  I do know I'm not the only person to use this convention.

Comment: I've seen ? used before in that context, but not !.

Comment: Maybe some people use ! to indicate happiness, like "woohoo!!"

Comment: I use ! for "this must be true! it is equivalent to the result" and ? for "is this true? it implies the result".

Comment: I'd be wary of such things. After all, students can find themselves scared of the notation you're using already, and sometimes it could really do without the extra burden of conveying emotion.
There are words which are quick to write which would do the same in a more human fashion, like "hopefully" or "woohoo!!".
Besides, it turns out that if you overuse these things when the context is not clear, then people start asking MathOverflow questions wondering what they mean...

Comment: I have encountered that notation with the interpretation "should be" or "we want it to be" e.g. in the context of optimization problems if one is more interested in the parameters that yield the maximum value than in the value of the maximum itself.

Comment: @James Cranch: People talk about far more pedantic things than this on Math Overflow.  And there's more elementary conventions in mathematics that would throw a student more easily than this.  If anything I find the slightly non-standard notation helps students get over the fact that they really ought to ask about notation.

Comment: I believe that it indicates that the we would like to set

Answer (score 21):

I propose that we adopt the usage of [algebraic chess annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_annotation_symbols), where the exclamation point ! indicates a particularly good move, which is also suprising or unexpected.

In mathematics, $\stackrel{!}{=}$ should denote a useful, important, but unexpected equality.

Comment: !?  (Interesting move)

Comment: And surely I've written ?? often enough when grading exams.

Comment: Example: $\mathord\vdash\stackrel{!}{=}\mathord\vDash$.

Comment: Honestly, this is exactly what I thought when this question bubbled up to the front page!

Answer (score 8):

I've seen it used as "has to be equal to"; the typical example is the point in a derivation when we use information we know by some general argument.

Comment: I learnt that way to use it in physics classes (and use it heavily myself, very useful).

Answer (score 4):

In my class I use $f'(x)  \stackrel{!}{=} 0 $ to show that we look for a zero of the derivative of $f$ in order to find a local extremum or a stationary point. Other requirements like the definition of a normalization factor are possible candidates.

Comment: That is exactly what I learned, and I feel it's totally obvious: it indicates a condition that must be met. But it seems that this is not a universally agreed notation, and it has the potential to cause  quite some confusion. So, perhaps I should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it means the same thing as the slightly more common $\stackrel{.}{=}$ or $\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}$ --- that the two sides of the equation are equal by definition.

Comment: I use Pascal notation for those conventions $x := y$. 

Comment: The $x:=y$ notation is my favorite too, but see J. S. Milne’s opinion in http://jmilne.org/math/words.html 

Comment: Milne may have a point, but as I see it, most of his argument applies to *any* decoration placed over $=$ to denote definitions. In particular, if the context makes it clear we are defining something, one should use plain $=$ (or say it in words).