# Equal signs with fancy marks

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics, notation, mathematical-writing

Some people use $\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}$, $:=$ or $\stackrel{\Delta}{=}$ for definitions.
In more informal contexts, I have also seen $\stackrel{?}{=}$, for "I wish to prove this equality, which implies the thesis", used when working backwards, or even the less common $\stackrel{!}{=}$ (for which it is difficult to infer a precise meaning, but it's something like "we are imposing this equality", or "this is an Ansatz").

It seems like the use of these symbols is not common in papers (apart from maybe the first ones for definitions); however, they seem useful to me as a way to convey more meaning than the usual equality symbols. For instance, in some sense the "?" superscript changes the set of "allowed operations": from $a=c$ and $b=d$ it follows that $a+b=c+d$, but the same implications wouldn't hold with $\stackrel{?}{=}$ signs.

Q1: has the use of these symbols ever been properly formalized?

Q2: are there contexts in which they are used in papers? Are they standard in your field? Are they used in lectures/seminars/papers?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11077/what-does-above-mean

Comment: E.g. one specific use of an equal sign with a question mark on top is described in Epp, Susanna S., Discrete mathematics with applications, Companion website: http://www.cengage.com/cgi-wadsworth/course_products_wp.pl?fid=M63&product_isbn_issn=9780495391326&chapter_number=0&resource_id=21&altname=Mathematical%20Induction%20Formats

Comment: A very nonstandard use of “an equal sign with a question mark on top” for mathematics education is suggested in http://cimm.ucr.ac.cr/resoluciondeproblemas/PDFs/Yerushalmy,M.%20Gilead,S.%20Structures%20of%20constant...pdf (see page 188 and page 202). It’s about a simple equation in one unknown.

Comment: You write "from $a = c$ and $b = d$ it follows that $a+c = b+d$". That's not true.

Comment: @KConrad Fixed, sorry.

Comment: Some people use $\equiv$ for definitions (as opposed to congruence); see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: The use of $:=$ seems quite standard, and has the advantage over some of the others of not breaking the line.

Comment: If you use :=, you want to make sure to use proper typesetting. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4216/how-to-typeset-correctly

Comment: The $:=$ from Pascal is now widely seen as a mistake --- since assignement is much more common that testing for equality, why have a shorter symbol for the former?. This and the decline of Pascal means the original motivation for its usage has largely disappeared.

Comment: @Waldemar I very much like the first example you give but not the second. The first one is questioning are they equal, which is fine by me. In the second however... when we solve say $x^2+x=0$ we are not questioning which values of $x$ solve the equation. Instead we should begin by assuming $x$ is a solution so that $x^2+x=0$ and deducing $x=0$ or $-1$. I agree with non-standard but I could say worse.

Comment: Some people use = with a dot on top (dunno how to typset it) to mean "up to a unit", see e.g. https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~ausoni/papers/kk-morava.pdf page 1060.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One context in which the distinction between "equal by definition" and "equal because we proved it" has a precise mathematical meaning is intensional dependent type theory.  This includes formalizing mathematics in a computer proof assistant based on ITT, such as [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) or [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), but mathematics in ITT can also be done "unformalized" such as in the [homotopy type theory book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book).

As for notation:

- Coq uses $=$ for propositional equality (i.e. "we proved it" equality) and $:=$ for definitional equality (more precisely, for definitions currently being made).
- Agda uses $=$ for definitions being made, and (at least in the standard library) $\equiv$ for propositional equality.
- The HoTT book uses $=$ for propositional equality, $\equiv$ for an equality that holds by definition but is not something *currently* being defined, and $:\equiv$ for something currently being defined.

  We spent a long time deciding on this; we wanted to use $=$ for "ordinary" equality, and we wanted to use something symmetric like $\equiv$ for equalities-by-previous-definition and something asymmetric like $:=$ for current-definitions so as to indicate visually that the *left* side is what's being defined.  But $:=$ for a current-definition would suggest that it's a *propositional* equality that results rather than a definitional one, which led us to invent the symbol $:\equiv$.  (We then actually ended up using $:=$ later for a "propositional equality being currently defined to hold", which happens under some versions of higher inductive types.)

Answer (score 6):

In a slightly different direction, $\overset{\mbox{(2.3)}}{\ge}$ (the overset should be in a smaller font using \tiny, but for some reason that wouldn't render here) is a nice way to indicate that the inequality uses $(2.3)$ - this is especially convenient with a long string of inequalities in display-math where it's otherwise hard work to figure out which inequality uses which previous calculation.